# How to find method of child classes?

Tags: java, class, java-8, abstract-class

I'm working on building some classes which will represent data to be converted to JSON.

The values of these fields could be of various types (might be an int, might be a boolean).

This is an example of what I have so far (minimum reproducible example):

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObjectBuilder;

abstract class AttributeValue {}

class AttributeValueInt extends AttributeValue {
    private int value;

    AttributeValueInt( int value ) {this.value = value;}

    int getValue() { return value; }
}

class AttributeValueBool extends AttributeValue {
    private boolean value;

    AttributeValueBool( boolean value ) {this.value = value;}

    boolean getValue() { return value; }
}

class Attribute {
    private AttributeValue attrValue;

    Attribute( AttributeValue attrValue ) { this.attrValue = attrValue; }

    AttributeValue getAttrValue() { return attrValue; }
}

class Example {
    void getJSON( Attribute attribute ) {
        JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        builder.add( "key", attribute.getAttrValue().getValue() );
        // Cannot resolve method 'getValue()'
    }
}
```

i.e. `AttributeValueInt` and `AttributeValueBool` extend the abstract class `AttributeValue`. `value` (towards the bottom) may be either an AttributeValueInt or an AttributeValueBool.

Since both these classes implement a `getValue` method, I was hoping that `attribute.getAttrValue().getValue()` would resolve to either an int or a boolean accordingly.

The full error is this:

```
Error:(39, 61) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getValue()
  location: class com.fanduel.brazepublishing.AttributeValue
```

How can I get this working? I thought about adding an abstract `getValue` method to the abstract class, but what would its return type be?

Comment: Have you considered using generics?

Comment: @akuzminykh I've never used generics. Can you elaborate on how it would work?

Comment: [Here](https://www.journaldev.com/1663/java-generics-example-method-class-interface) is a tutorial about generics and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) is the official one. Don't worry, it just seems difficult in the beginning. When you know how to use generics, this will be a huge step towards writing very well designed, readable and maintainable code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic for that. Here an example:

```java
abstract class AttributeValue<AttributeType> {
    AttributeType value;

    AttributeType getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}


class AttributeValueInt extends AttributeValue<Integer> {
    AttributeValueInt(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}


class AttributeValueBool extends AttributeValue<Boolean> {
    AttributeValueBool(boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}


class Main {


    static String getJson(AttributeValue<?> attribute) {
        return "key: " + attribute.getValue();
    } 


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AttributeValue<?> attributeInt = new AttributeValueInt(42);
        AttributeValue<?> attributeBool = new AttributeValueBool(true);

        System.out.println(getJson(attributeInt));
        System.out.println(getJson(attributeBool));
    }
}
```

Here you can call `getValue` on an `AttributeValue` instance as the type of the attribute is specified by `<AttributeType>`. One drawback is that you can't use primitive types anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this. But since you have mentioned the `AttributeValue` can be of any type, you can simply use `Map<K, V>`

```java
// String - key
// Object - Any value type

Map<String, Object> jsonFields = new HashMap<>();

// populate the Map

JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder();

for(Map.Entry<String, Object> currentEntry : jsonFields.entrySet()) {
    builder.add(currentEntry.getKey(), currentEntry.getValue());
}
```

With this way, you would have separate keys for each mapped values. Or if you still wanna stick with `AttributeValue` implementations, you can acheive like below. Since, `Object` is the parent class for all the Java classes, this will work.

```java
abstract class AttributeValue {
    public abstract Object getValue();
}

class AttributeValueInt extends AttributeValue {
    private int value;

    public AttributeValueInt(int value) {this.value = value;}

    @Override
    public Object getValue() { return value; }
}

class AttributeValueBool extends AttributeValue {
    private boolean value;

    public AttributeValueBool(boolean value) {this.value = value;}

    @Override
    public Object getValue() { return value; }
}

public class Main {

    static void getJSON( Attribute attribute ) {
        JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        builder.add( "key", attribute.getAttrValue().getValue() );
        // rest of your code
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. attribute.getAttrValue().getValue() returns an Object, and  JsonObjectBuilder's add method doesn't accept an Object.

Comment: Oops. Then the other option would be to go with generic programming only as in other answers